# OpenTBS not working on Ubuntu 14.04 with PHP5.5.9

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu-14.04, lamp, opentbs

Am using openTBS version 1.9.4 [enter link description here](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php) on Ubunto 14.04 with PHP5.5.9. while am using this application I figured out, where the problem occurs.

```
// Include classes
include_once('tbs_class.php'); // Load the TinyButStrong template engine
include_once('../tbs_plugin_opentbs.php'); // Load the OpenTBS plugin

// prevent from a PHP configuration problem when using mktime() and date()
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION,'5.1.0')>=0) {
    if (ini_get('date.timezone')=='') {
        date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
    }
}

// Initialize the TBS instance
$TBS = new clsTinyButStrong; // new instance of TBS
```

I am facing the problem while creating the instance TBS and it throws the following error on chrome browser.

```
No data received

ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

But I tried the same openTBS version 1.9.4 on WAMP2.5 with PHP5.5.12, it's working.
I also tried the same openTBS version 1.9.4 on RHEL-7.1_HVM_GA with PHP5.4.16, It's working

Comment: TBS is platform independent, so it would be surprising that there is the problem comes from TBS. Error ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE can be caused by the navigator, a bugged Apache extension, or more rarely a PHP version, ... It would be interesting if you could find which TBS line make this bug to occur.

Comment: Now it's working when I disable xcache cacher @Skrol29

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, I configure the xcache on php and it's not working. When I tried to remove the xcache parameter "xcache.cacher" from On to Off in

> xcache.ini

it's working.

```
xcache.cacher =               Off
```